# How to handle reusable components in React?

Tags: reactjs, code-reuse

I'm trying to make a reusable input component. When data enters I want to handle those input data in the same place where I use that reusable input component. Not passing that as props.
I'm getting an error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`
Can anyone give me any idea about how to handle data in such an instance?

InputFieldWithImage.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Form, FormGroup, Input } from 'reactstrap';

function InputFieldWithImage(props) {
  const [inputType] = useState(props.type)
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  function handleChange(event){
    console.log("Input.js");
    console.log(inputValue);
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
    if(props.onChange) props.onChange(inputValue)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Input type={inputType} value={inputValue} name="input-form" onChange={handleChange} class="inputclass"/>
    </>
  );
}
export default InputFieldWithImage;
```

AddTicket.js

```
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Form, FormGroup, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import ActionButton from './../../components/ButtonComponent';
import InputFieldWithImage from './../../components/InputField/InputFieldWithImage'
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

const AddTicket = (props) => {
 
  const [assignee, setAssignee] = useState('');
 

  
  const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
   
    console.log('Assignee:' + assignee);
    
    props.handleClose();
  };

  const test = () => {
    console.log("text");
    console.log('Assignee:' + assignee);
  };

  return (
    <div className="popup-box">
      <div className="box">
        {/* <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>
          x
        </span> */}
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{paddingLeft:30,paddingTop:50}}>
          <Row style={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}>
            <Col sm={11} xs={11} md={11}>
              <h1>Add new ticket </h1>
            </Col>
            <Col onClick={props.handleClose} m={1} xs={1} md={1}>
              <h1 className="close-icon">X </h1>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          


          <FormGroup>
            <Row style={{ marginBottom: '25px' }}>
              <Col sm={2}>
                <h4>Assignee</h4>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={2}>
                <InputFieldWithImage value={assignee} onChange={(e) => setAssignee(e.target.value)} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </FormGroup>

         
          <Row>
            <Col sm={2}></Col>
            <Col>
              <ActionButton text="Send" />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTicket;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `event` instead of `inputValue` . As there is `input.target.value` . That's why its giving error

```
function handleChange(event) {
    console.log("Input.js");
    console.log(inputValue);
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(event);
  }
```

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-tree-vr834?file=/src/App.js